# MAGENTO, "Manage Products" -> Blank screen on Add/Modify Item (ReferenceError)

Tags: magento, magmi, referenceerror

Good evening people,

I'm trying to MODIFY a previously added item - but this blank screen occurs

(https://www.dropbox.com/s/fp4udpg31iss5u5/Screenshot%202014-10-18%2018.03.42.png?dl=0)

Same happens when try to ADD a NEW PRODUCT.

PLUS: While debugging on Mozilla Firefox, on the missing product grid it shows me a serie of "ReferenceError". What is missing ?

I've been searching for similar questions but I've got no clue on how to solve it.
This problem shows after a massive loading of about 300 items' images using Magmi.

UnderstandingE's version of Magmi.
Magento version 1.5.0.1.

Comment: did you check logs (you have to turn them on)? Can you post part which points this action?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Krzysztof !

Yes, I've got the log enabled. 
Here's an excerpt: the messages which are repeated on and on in the "System.log"
https://www.dropbox.com/s/3fk2h71cwei5t6y/system.log.txt?dl=0

And here there are the relative files too:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/pq0t4irv779t65a/Files.zip?dl=0

Comment: Did you clear cache and reindex all data (even if it shows that index is indexed) (i ask for it in answer but someone delete it, if it help i undelete answer).

Comment: "Flush Magento cache", then "Reindex (all) data" - nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED !

Checking my FTP log, I've found a modified version of "browser.js" file.
This file was containing invalid characters.

I've found the clue by pressing F12 on Mozilla Firefox, 
and reading in the Console about some "SyntaxError" and "ReferenceError".

"Browser.js" modified by a simple NotePad and then uploaded via FTP by an unaware user.

Thank you so much for the help...hope this will help too!

*Tom*

(A mention is needed: this riddle was actually solved by the brilliant *hostingpartner.it "Customer Care"*)